# Hide/mask subdomain in addressbar with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use .htaccess in www.mydomain.com to redirect specific IP's to subdomain www2.mydomain.com.
All fine there.

Now I want to hide the fact that you are on www2.mydomain.com by changing it so the addressbar shows www.mydomain.com, is that possible?

Both www.mydomain.com and www2.mydomain.com are on the same hosting.

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: hm so it would be possible to rewrite so those IP's only see the content of www2.mydomain.com instead of www.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're seeking to make both domain names contain the same application folder.

In a typical LAMP environment using virtual hosts, you can point multiple virtual hosts to the same folder. This means you'll have to go a little deeper in your configurations, not just the .htaccess files. You'll need SSH/root access to your remote server. If its locally served then navigate away. the virtualhosts you're looking for are www2.mydomain.com and mydoamin.com

1. Find your httpd.conf file. This is usually stored in the Apache application directory.
2. Make sure virtual host module is enabled
3. Define or modify virtual hosts to point to the same document root.
4. Save, and restart Apache (make sure there's no config errors or
   it'll fail to restart)

If you're on a platform that utilizes parallels or cpanel, there should be a local configuration file inside each vhosts folder that contains a similar virtual host config. This is typical since it reduces the chance of messing up the whole server when playing around with core apache configs.

Comment: Hi, no acctually I want different content in www2.mydomain.com but the redirected visitors shouldn't be able to see that they are on the subdomain. So basically just "fake" the subdomain name. Or am I not getting you post? Thanks :)

Comment: oh right, yeah I think that falls align with security. If you're allowed to spoof urls I could be bankofamerica.com.

Comment: get your point, but thought there might be different rules for subdomains. like if you got mirrorsites on different subdomains for example, but still just see the main domain in the addressbar.